# How to hide axis labels in python pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I've used the following code to generate a dataframe which is supposed to be the input for a seaborn plot.

```py
data_array = np.array([['index', 'value']])
for x in range(len(value_list)):
    data_array = np.append(data_array, np.array([[int((x + 1)), int(value_list[x])]]), axis = 0)
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data_array)
```

The output looks something like this:

```
      0       1
0 index  values
1     1 value_1
2     2 value_2
3     3 value_3
```

However, with this dataframe, seaborn returns an error. When comparing my data to the examples, I see that the first row is missing. The samples, being loaded in with load_dataset(), look something like this:

```
0 index  values
1     1 value_1
2     2 value_2
3     3 value_3
```

How do I remove the first row of axis labels of my dataframe so that it looks like the samples provided? Removing the first row removes the strings "index" and "values", but not the axis label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy thinks that `index` and `values` row is also a row of the values of the dataframe and not the names of the columns.

I think this would be more pythonic way of doing this:

```
pd.DataFrame(list(enumerate(value_list, 1)), columns=['index', 'values'])
```

Comment: @jezrael Agree. Other answers are also correct, but they seem to not seeing how `data_array` is produced in the first place. It can be done much simpler

Answer (score 1):

just slice your dataframe

```
df =data_frame[2:]
df.columns = data_frame.iloc[1] --it will set the column name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
new_header = df.iloc[0] #grab the first row for the header
df = df[1:] #take the data less the header row
df.columns = new_header #set the header row as the df header
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what `value_list` is. However I would recommend another way to create dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

value_list = ['10', '20', '30']

data_frame = pd.DataFrame({
    'index': range(len(value_list)),
    'value': [int(x) for x in value_list]})
```

`data_frame`:

```
   index value
0      0    10
1      1    20
2      2    30
```

Now you can easily change dataframe index and 'index' column:

```
data_frame.loc[:, 'index'] += 1
data_frame.index += 1
```

`data_frame`:

```
   index value
1      1    10
2      2    20
3      3    30
```

Comment: I think `'value'` are strings. So just `'value': value_list`.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych The code in the question contains `int(value_list[x])`. So I guess some type conversion may be needed. Of course it may be done later by pandas means.

Comment: Yeah. Probably OPs example is not consistent with code that generates it.